# jad "Version mismatch: major.minor = 49.0, expected = 45.3", what's version of .class file?

Tags: decompiling, jad

I used jad to decompile the class but in AIX system, such error thrown.

```
Version mismatch: major.minor = 49.0, expected = 45.3
```

I don't know what's the version of .class file, how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class was compiled for JDK5, your tools only support JDK1.1.

You probably need a newer version of jad (or the whole JDK) on that machine (or compile your code for an older version of Java).

[major version number of the class file format being used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file):

```
J2SE 7 = 51 (0x33 hex),
J2SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex),
J2SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex),
JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex),
JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex),
JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex),
JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex).
```