# Is there a command decompiling tool supports Windows/Linux/AIX like JAD does for JDK5 class?

Tags: java, decompiling

I was using [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/) (No longer update?) for decompiling the .class file, but on AIX or Linux, jdk 5 class is not supported by JAD, (replied by @Thilo , in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361955/jad-version-mismatch-major-minor-49-0-expected-45-3-whats-version-of)).

I know some decompiling tools are based on JAD, but is there such a tool both provides commandline interface(I know DJ has a GUI which I don't want it) that I can call it from Java and supports JDK5 .class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is one, it was a French project hosted on free.fr. Luckily for you, Archive.org´s wayback machine has it indexed,including the download binaries.

It decompiles Java 1.5 and 1.6 too.

Here is the link 
http://web.archive.org/web/20110416091052/http://java.decompiler.free.fr/